# How to determine both the primal and dual solution for a min problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Consider the minimization problem

$$
\min 5x_1 + 2x_2 + 4x_3
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
3x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 & \geq 4 \\
6x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 & \geq 10 \\
x_1, x_2, x_3 & \geq 0
\end{align}
My question: I have found the dual problem to the minimazation that being
$$
\max 4y_1 + 10y_2
$$
subject to
\begin{align}
3y_1 + 6y_2 & \leq 5 \\
y_1 + 3y_2 & \leq 2 \\
2y_1 + 5y_2 & \leq 4 \\
y_1,y_2 & \geq 0
\end{align}
and have found the optimal solution $y* = (y_1*,y_2*) = (1,1/3)$.

However, now I am asked to specify an optimal solution for both the primal and the dual problem but I am not sure how to? I tried to solve the minimization problem using the simplex method, but I just couldn't figure it out. All the videos, I have watched, said to do it by solving the dual problem.. What do I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can solve them both by the simplex method. Also, the primal has three decision variables, so your solution is incomplete.

Comment: I meant that $y* = (1,1/3)$. Isn't that correct?

Comment: I think I figured it out..

Comment: @Mathias What have you figured out?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply complementary slackness to obtain $x_3=0$ (because $2y_1^*+5y_2^*<4$) and $3x_1 + x_2 + 2x_3 = 4$ and $6x_1 + 3x_2 + 5x_3 = 10$ (because $y_1^* > 0$ and $y_2^* > 0$).